# How to solve Android SQLite rounding error

Tags: android, sqlite, rounding, rounding-error

We have problem in our Android application with rounding numbers. In calculation made in Java we use BigDecimal and this helps, but we have problem with SQLite, for ex.

```
SELECT ROUND(150.075 * 100) / 100 (= 150.07, not 150.08!)
```

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q16

Comment: @Selvin Yes, i know it - but search for solution, if possible.

Comment: store data as int ... like 150075 ... then in java code use BigDecimal(150075 , 3)

Answer (score 1):

What you think about this (not elegant) solution:

```
SELECT ROUND(150.075 + 0.00000000000009, 2) (= 150.08)
```

We checked it on more then 5 000 incorrect values and it's works good.

Answer (score 0):

That's because due to floating point inaccuracies, `150.075 * 100` is not the same as `15007.5`. The decimal representation for `150.075` in double-precision floating point is `150.07499999999999999722444243843711`.

To get the behavior you want, use the two-argument version of `ROUND()` which lets you specify the number of decimal digits:

```
sqlite> SELECT ROUND(150.075, 2);
150.08
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a good solution. In Android SQLite (but in Google Chrome too) SELECT ROUND(150.075, 2) returns 150.07. We noticed that sometimes one number is right on OSX and wrong on Windows... and vice versa.

Comment: @ekstro Internally, sqlite uses its own `printf()` for rounding and some versions of it have similar floating point inaccuracies.